# Cross-comparing values from a csv file in Python3

Tags: python

I have a CSV file with values (pure example)

```
A, B, C, D
```

I'm looking to compare each of the values to itself and the other members in the file, the end result is the following:

```
A A
A B
A C
A D
B A
B B
B C
B D
C A
C B
C C
C D
D A 
D B
D C
D D
```

How should I tackle this problem?

**EDIT:**
Hey all, here are some more clarifications.
The csv file has the following columns: ZIP code (postcode), Community (Gemeente), Latitude, Longitude and Coords (the combination of Latitude,Longitude). I'm trying to calculate the distance in kilometers between each of the ZIP codes.
Here's what I have:

```
import pandas as pd 
import geopy from geopy 
import distance df = pd.read_csv('MonkeyProof_postcodes_developer.csv') 

for leftval in df['Postcode']: 
    for rightval in df['Postcode']: print(leftval,rightval, 
       df.loc[leftval, 'Coords'], df.loc[rightval, 'Coords'])
```

Link to source file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pN53cbB6zsT9Q9v4VB2ixfBP2BiG5VcY52mYsPR1UFs/edit?usp=sharing

Kind regards

Comment: What do you mean "compare"—are they numbers and you want to know which is greater? Is this a single row of data, and you want to do this for each row? Is your intended output really just the two values next to each other like that?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are working with and trying to achieve? Does your csv contain only one line? Are you trying to create all *combinations* of the elements in the csv?

Comment: Hey all, here are some more clarifications.
The csv file has the following columns: ZIP code (postcode), Community (Gemeente), Latitude, Longitude and Coords (the combination of Latitude,Longitude). 
I'm trying to calculate the distance in kilometers between each of the ZIP codes. 

Here's what I have:
import pandas as pd
import geopy
from geopy import distance

df = pd.read_csv('MonkeyProof_postcodes_developer.csv')

for leftval in df['Postcode']:
    for rightval in df['Postcode']:
        print(leftval,rightval, df.loc[leftval, 'Coords'], df.loc[rightval, 'Coords'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best" way really depends on what you want to do, but a general way is to use a double for-loop:

```py
>>> values = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> for leftval in values:
...     for rightval in values:
...         print(leftval, rightval)
...
A A
A B
A C
A D
B A
B B
B C
B D
C A
C B
C C
C D
D A
D B
D C
D D
```

If you want to do numeric computations you can probably achieve good performance using `numpy` and such, but then again it depends on your problem.

Comment: Hey, I have implemented your reply in my original post - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete way to solve your problem.

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['A','B','C','D']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['data'])

temp = df.data.to_list()
for ii in temp:
    for jj in temp:
        print(ii, jj)
```

Comment: Why create a dataframe from the list when you just extract the original list again?

Comment: If you read his problem statement carefully - he has a csv file. He will load it as Panda data frame. So I created a dataframe and solve the problem as he was expecting.